# @UrlQueryString not working for http://www.myserver.com/foo.nsf/&L=EN

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I'm creating a custom General Error Message (in domcfg that will replace the standard HTTP404)
I want to get the parameters on the URL, so I use @UrlQueryString.
It works fine expect for URL with the following syntax:
 
http://www.myserver.com/foo.nsf/&L=EN
For this URL the @UrlQueryString returns and empty string.

QUESTION: How Can I get the parameter of the URL in a bad formed URL ?

Comment: I've never seen a URL like that, no surprises that Domino doesn't like it. Its effectively a malformed http Post request but can you share where its coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server variable PATH_INFO will tell you what the current URL is.

See more info on server variables here:  http://www.angelfire.com/ult/tipslotusnotes/Special%20Fields,%20Reserved%20Fields%20and%20Special%20Design%20Elements.htm